# VBA EXCEL - "When" you select a particular cell

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if it was possible to "do something" WHEN the "selection" is going on a specific cell?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event. Plenty of examples are available on SO.

Comment: The answer is "Yes". Did you even *try* before asking?

Comment: Seems the *Object Browser* could be your new best friend. Hit F2 in the VBE, select the Excel type library, and browse to the members of the `Workbook` and `Worksheet` classes. Look for events.

Comment: I'll check that. I'm new in vba excel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the selection changed event in combination with the Intersect function to see if the selected cells overlap with a particular range.  You'd be checking if the new selection was in A1:z99 in the example below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z99")) Is Nothing Then
        'Code to do something useful
    Else
        'Do Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Alternatively, the `SheetSelectionChange` event of the `Workbook` class can be used if we don't care which worksheet was involved, or if we want to handle worksheets' `SelectionChange` event for all sheets in the workbook at once / the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the help!